# Boxtree/circletree in VIM?

Tags: vim

Does VIM (or macvim) have a way to show a code-folding boxtree/circletree like Notepad++?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `:help folding`.  There are a gazillion ways to customize it, but putting `set foldmethod=syntax` in your `$MYVIMRC` works for most cases.  You can get little plus signs to click on in the GUI by setting `foldcolumn` to something.